# Laravel token authentication security issue

Tags: php, laravel

I am newbie in laravel framework. I want to integrate a new API in the existing laravel project. It has already implemented a token based authentication with guards

config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

and in the routes, I have added the a **GET** request of the project

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function() {

    Route::get('friends', 'UserController@friends')->name('api.user.friends');
}
```

But now I can access the friend list using URL like this

```
http://yourapp.com/api/friends?api_token=STORED_TOKEN_HERE
```

instead of passing the **api_token** in the header. Is this a security issue or is this the method used in laravel?

There is already a GET(logout) URL that works this way in the app

Comment: Well it's only less secure than the header if someone is behind you reading your address bar and able to memorise the token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is: **do you want (or need)** your app to allow passing this access token in query params? 
By that I mean: does it have to use tokens in URLs (in some cases? in all cases? or not at all?)

Generally speaking anything security-related should not be a part of URL (unless it's part of a Single-Sign-On procedure - then there's hardly any other choice, but the tokens have a short lifetime and it's a subject for a separate post ;) ). 
So if you want your app to follow best practices, disable passing access token in query and retrieve it only from request headers, as [described in the Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_header).

So you should probably look into your middleware and (I guess) change the code from `Request::input('api_token')` to `Request::header('api_token')`, so there is no way anyone authenticates by passing api token in URL.

Comment: Is the middleware for token implemented as part of the laravel library?

Answer (score 0):

I think that's not the Laravel method for API authentication. You should use Laravel passport, check the amazing Laravel doc https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport

Laravel already makes it easy to perform authentication via traditional login forms, but what about APIs? APIs typically use tokens to authenticate users and do not maintain session state between requests. Laravel makes API authentication a breeze using Laravel Passport, which provides a full OAuth2 server implementation for your Laravel application in a matter of minutes. Passport is built on top of the League OAuth2 server that is maintained by Andy Millington and Simon Hamp.

To get started, install Passport via the Composer package manager:

```
composer require laravel/passport
```

The Passport service provider registers its own database migration directory with the framework, so you should migrate your database after registering the provider. The Passport migrations will create the tables your application needs to store clients and access tokens:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Next, you should run the passport:install command. This command will create the encryption keys needed to generate secure access tokens. In addition, the command will create "personal access" and "password grant" clients which will be used to generate access tokens:

```
php artisan passport:install
```

For more info check the official Laravel documentation

Comment: Its already implemented in the project and token based api URL is working using it. But current api's are all using POST method and parameter is passing in the request body. So we cannot change the existing structure.

Comment: If you can't change the implementation then use Lkeskowy's solution and try passing the token via the request header